# Nested listview in flutter should scroll into the outside listview when scroll boundaries reach

Tags: flutter, listview, scroll

I have a listview that has another listview nested within it. The second listview is inside a constrained box. When I scroll to the end of the inner list view I want it to transition automatically to outer listview scrolling. Is this possible?

Here is briefly what I am trying to do ?

```
ListView.builder(
    itemBuilder: (_,__) {
      ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: BoxConstraints(
              maxHeight: MediaQuery
                  .of(context)
                  .size
                  .height * 0.5),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                  children: [Text("Large text" /*Large Text */)]
              )
          )
      );
    }
);
```

When I scroll through my inner ScrollView() if I reach the end of the view I would like it to scroll to the outer scroll view. I have tried setting different ScrollPhysics() but they did not do the trick.

Comment: check this [answere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60579335/flutter-listview-scroll-parent-listview-when-child-listview-reach-bottom-c)