# How to implemented Nested ListView.builder in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, custom-scrolling

I have already gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45270900/how-to-implement-nested-listview-in-flutter) post

for nested scrolling but it is not the correct way according to me as explained in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LUqDNnv_dh0) video from the official flutter channel

I want to achieve the below layout

[image]

The list header like Claim requested credentials,Claim received credentials,Pending Requests etc are dynamic and will be coming from backend. Also each item in those list header like Module 1: Designing Financial Services are also dynamic

So I need list within a list

I am using a CustomScroll but I am not able to achieve the inner list view

I am looking for a lazy list option and not just mapping the inner list over a column or a list as the inner list might contain 100 items

Here is what I have achieved

[image]

Here is the sample code

```
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          HeaderGradient(),
          Positioned(
            top: 110,
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            bottom: 0,
            child: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                color: grayColor,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                  topRight: Radius.circular(20),
                ),
              ),
              child: CustomScrollView(
                slivers: [
                  const SliverToBoxAdapter(
                    child: ManageCredentialHeader(),
                  ),
                  SliverList(
                      delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((context, index) {
                    return ManageCredentialCard();
                  }, childCount: 10))
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and

```
class ManageCredentialCard extends StatelessWidget {
  const ManageCredentialCard({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.background,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8, vertical: 4),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            const ManageCredentialCardHeader(),

            const ManageCredentialCardItem()
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`ManageCredentialCardItem` is the inner list

As soon as I wrap `ManageCredentialCardItem` inside a `ListView.builder` I get error saying

```
RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are
unbounded.
When a column is in a parent that does not provide a finite height constraint,
for example if it is
in a vertical scrollable, it will try to shrink-wrap its children along the
vertical axis. Setting a
flex on a child (e.g. using Expanded) indicates that the child is to expand to
fill the remaining
space in the vertical direction.
```

Check the [sample repo](https://github.com/PritishSawant/FlutterDummyScrolling) to check what I have tried and full source code

Comment: you dont need to have `ManageCredentialCardItem` ListView, parent widget already handling the scroll-event. You can use Column instead.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I don't want to use Column as there are might 100 elements in the list. I need something which will lazy load and reuse the views like Listview.builder does

Comment: try to return SliverList on that case

Comment: SliverList for the inner list as well?

Comment: no i mean just return like method. also you can try with `primary:false` for inner scollable widget

Comment: @YeasinSheikh Please share a code sample. Sorry I don't understand what you mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was referring generating everything on sliver like

```dart
child: CustomScrollView(
  slivers: [
    const SliverToBoxAdapter(
      child: ManageCredentialHeader(),
    ),
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
      SliverPadding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: 8, vertical: 4),
        sliver: SliverList(
          delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
              childCount: 10 + 1, //extend by 1 for header
              (context, index) {
            return index == 0
                ? const ManageCredentialCardHeader()
                : const ManageCredentialCardItem();
          }),
        ),
      )
  ],
),
```

Also you can create custom-sliver for children.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the ‘ListView.builder’ problem, I suggest to wrap it into an ’Expanded’ and set the ’shrinkWrap’ property of the ’ListView’ to true.

As for the list inside a list problem I’m not sure I understand correctly, but setting the ’primary’ property of the inner List to false should make it so it follows the scroll of the general list and avoids scrolling internally.

It might be needed to also set the ’shrinkWrap’ to true since it has no defined height, making it not lazy, but I’d try also wrapping it with ’Expanded’ as it might have the same result keeping it lazy

Comment: Tried both shrinkWrap and Expanded. It does not work

Answer (score 0):

As @Yeasin Sheikh suggested, you dont need to use `Listview.builder` inside `ManageCredentialCardItem` because the parent of `ManageCredentialCardItem` is handling the scroll i.e

```
 SliverList(    //  This will handle scroll
      delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((context, index) {
          return ManageCredentialCard(); // So you can use column instead
       },childCount: 10))
```

---

If you have useCase where you have to use `ListView.builder` for fetching the results from remote source, you can use `shrinkWrap: true` prop inside `ListView.builder`

Comment: Yes I already have SliverList which handle scroll as you can see in the question. I do not want to use column or Listview for ManageCredentialCard as that won't be lazy loading the items. Using Listview.builder causes issue which I mentioned in my question

Comment: have you tried using `shrinkWrap:true` did it solve your problem

Comment: yes I have tried that as well

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure about what effect you want to achieve, but :

If your goal is to display the full list of items in your `ManageCredentialCard` like this:

[image]

you just need to update the `ManageCredentialCard` widget with the following

```
class ManageCredentialCard extends StatelessWidget {
  const ManageCredentialCard({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.background,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8, vertical: 4),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            const ManageCredentialCardHeader(),
            ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return const ManageCredentialCardItem();
              },
              itemCount: 20,
            )
            // const ManageCredentialCardItem()
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

BUT

If your goal is to limit the size of your `Cards`, and be able to scroll the Items list like this

[image]

you will have to define a height limit to your Cards with a `SizeBox`.

```
class ManageCredentialCard extends StatelessWidget {
  const ManageCredentialCard({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.background,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8, vertical: 4),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            const ManageCredentialCardHeader(),
            SizedBox(
              height: 150,
              child: ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return const ManageCredentialCardItem();
                },
                itemCount: 10,
              ),
            )
            // const ManageCredentialCardItem()
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The only thing you'll have to do then would be to scroll the main `Listview` when reaching the end of one of the inner-lists.
To do so, you can use the `NotificationListener` widget as explained in this post :
[Flutter : ListView : Scroll parent ListView when child ListView reach bottom - ClampingScrollPhysics not working in sized container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60579335/flutter-listview-scroll-parent-listview-when-child-listview-reach-bottom-c)